# Search 2D array in a class Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'll frame this in the fact that I'm kind of a newbie to 
Python and I'm taking my first stab at writing a class.  What I'd like to achieve is for the class to open one of a group of text files based on user input.  The text files contain information like this:

```
 20,21,22
 23,24,25
 26,27,28
```

The text file is read as a 2D array.  A value is read from this array and assigned to a new variable, so that the variable can be printed and also used later in a calculation.  I've been able to do this without difficulty outside of the class, but getting this to work in a class has been frustrating.  Here's the code I have so far for Python 2.7:

```
im_new = []

class Read(object):
    def __init__(self, agev, table, row, col, newvar):
        self.agevar = agev
        self.table = table
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.newvar = newvar

        display_list = []


        with open(self.table + str(self.agevar) + ".txt", "r") as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                display_list.append(line.strip().split(','))

    def __str__(self):
        self.newvar = (display_list[self.row][self.col])

immem = Read(40, "im", 1, 2, im_new)


print "Immediate Memory: " % im_new
```

Ideally, referencing the example text file, the output would be "Immediate Memory: 25", but the output I get is "Immediate Memory:" and when I print the value im_new in the console, I get "[]".  I'm sure it's something very obvious that I'm missing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but try `print "Immediate Memory: " % immem.newvar`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I made the change to the code that you suggested but no go with the output.  I agree that perhaps I did not explain what I was doing well.  I will revise my question and code and repost.  I appreciate your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your code, it doesn't also run. I tried to fix:

```
im_new = []

class Read(object):
    def __init__(self, agev, table, row, col, newvar):
        self.agevar = agev
        self.table = table
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.newvar = newvar

        self.display_list = []


        with open(self.table + str(self.agevar) + ".txt", "r") as data_file:
            for line in data_file:
                self.display_list.append(line.strip().split(','))

    def __str__(self):
        self.newvar = (self.display_list[self.row][self.col])
        return self.newvar

immem = Read(40, "im", 1, 2, im_new)


print "Immediate Memory: ", immem
```

This returns `Immediate Memory: 25` like you're expecting, but I'm not sure it's what you want.